# Jquery multiple flexible checkbox check checked and show textbox

Tags: jquery

I got multiple flexible checkbox which is all the checkbox records are from database. What I want to do is when I checked any checkbox, it's will show the textbox below of the checkbox.

**here is my page layout**

[image]

The screenshot now show all textbox, by default all textbox must be hide up.

**here is my code**

```
<?php $no = 0; if(isset($skill_records)) : foreach($skill_records as $row) : $no++; ?>

<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row->skillid; ?>" name="skillid[]"  id="skillid<?php echo $no; ?>"  <?php echo set_checkbox('skillid[]', $row->skillid); ?>>
<?php echo $row->skill; ?>
</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="display:none;">
<input type="text" value="" name="score[]" class="score input-sm form-control" id="score<?php echo $no; ?>" placeholder="Score"  >
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see my textbox already set as `display:none`

Any Idea how to do this is Jquery ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
    $(this).closest("div").next().toggle(this.checked);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bhewxedr/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').change(function(){

var target = $(this).closest('li').find('.CLASS_OF_INPUT');

if (this.checked) {
        target.show();
    }

});
```